# VSCode: The Flutter Daemon failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter, dart

При запуске VSCode всплывает ошибка: The Flutter Daemon failed to start. А также нет ни одного устройства

[image]

В терминале VSCode при любой команде Flutter появляется такое сообщение: Непредвиденное появление: <<.
[image]

Во flutter_console.bat flutter doctor показывает, что всё отлично.

В переменных среды путь до flutter/bin есть, однако, в cmd также появляется ошибка.

Из-за чего вообще могла возникнуть такая проблема? А главное - как её решить?

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблемы так:

- переустановила Flutter не просто на диск С, а в С:\src
- устанавливала не с помощью архива, а клонировала с GitHub

Пример в документации https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk